# Build Hyperledger Fabric with Docker on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to build Hyperledger Fabric images with Docker on Mac.
I installed prerequisites and git cloned fabric 1.4 and fabric-ca 1.4.
and I typed `make docker` inside of fabric directory.
When I did same on unbuntu virtual box, it had no problem.
However, I got error on Mac.(Mac Mojave 10.14.3)

Error log:

> Building docker peer-image
>
> docker build  -t hyperledger/fabric-peer .build/image/peer
>
> Sending build context to Docker daemon  33.35MB
>
> Step 1/7 : FROM hyperledger/fabric-baseos:amd64-0.4.14 ---> 
>   75f5fb1a0e0c
>
> Step 2/7 : ENV FABRIC_CFG_PATH /etc/hyperledger/fabric ---> Using cache
>   ---> 07fffab66f6c
>
> Step 3/7 : RUN mkdir -p /var/hyperledger/production $FABRIC_CFG_PATH
>   ---> Using cache 
>   ---> 12db028c5850
>
> Step 4/7 : COPY payload/peer /usr/local/bin
>
> ---> Using cache
>
> ---> 1182063498b1
>
> Step 5/7 : ADD  payload/sampleconfig.tar.bz2 $FABRIC_CFG_PATH
>
> failed to copy files: Error processing tar file(bzip2 data invalid: bad
>
> magic value in continuation file):
>
> make: *** [.build/image/peer/.dummy-amd64-1.4.1-snapshot-348c677c1]
>
> Error 1

I searched every web sites, but I cannot solve it.
Is there anyone know about this error ? I already tried: `brew install gnu-tar --with-default-names` and `brew install lib tool`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error building peer: "bzip2 data invalid" in goshim.tar.bz2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465720/error-building-peer-bzip2-data-invalid-in-goshim-tar-bz2)

Comment: @MostafaHussein Thank you for comment. Actually I tried it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I solved it by typing ->export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install gnu-tar
brew install libtool
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```